# How to continue row number while using pagination

Tags: laravel

can someone help me how to continue the row number? so when i change the page the row number continue from the previous page.
this is my **blade.php** file

```
<tbody>
                  @foreach ($data as $no => $row) 
                    <tr class="text-center">
                      <td scope="row">{{ ++$no }}</td>
                      <td>
                        @if ($row->id_suppplier < 10)
                            {{ $prefix='S-'.date('Ymd', strtotime($row->created_at)).$row->id_supplier}}
                        @endif
                      </td>
                      <td>{{ $row->nm_supplier }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $row->amt_supplier }}</td>
                      <td>0{{ $row->telp_supplier  }}</td>
                      <td>
                        <button type="button"  onclick="supplierEdit({{$row->id_supplier}})" data-idsupplier="{{ $row->id_supplier }}" class="btn btn-warning pl-4">Edit Data</button>
                        <a href="/delete/{{ $row->id_supplier }}"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
                {{ $data->links() }}
```

this is my **Controller.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $data = supplier::orderBy('id_supplier','ASC')->paginate(3);
    return view('supplier', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Get the starting row number using laravel paginator built-in `firstItem` method. And use laravel $loop to get current number of row.

```php
<tbody>
@foreach ($data as $row)
    <tr class="text-center">
        <td scope="row">{{ $data->firstItem() + $loop->index }}</td>
        <td>
            @if ($row->id_suppplier < 10)
                {{ $prefix='S-'.date('Ymd', strtotime($row->created_at)).$row->id_supplier}}
            @endif
        </td>
        <td>{{ $row->nm_supplier }}</td>
        <td>{{ $row->amt_supplier }}</td>
        <td>0{{ $row->telp_supplier  }}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button"  onclick="supplierEdit({{$row->id_supplier}})" data-idsupplier="{{ $row->id_supplier }}" class="btn btn-warning pl-4">Edit Data</button>
            <a href="/delete/{{ $row->id_supplier }}"  type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
{{ $data->links() }}
```

Comment: you can get this information directly from the paginator, `$start = $data->firstItem();` ;  "Get the number of the first item in the slice"

Comment: @lagbox yeah this is better. Thank you.